# ORA-06550 in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting an error when executing the following, and I want to display an error message instead of an error:

```
 declare 
   bday date not null := '13-sep-78';
 begin
    bday := '12-oct-09';
    bday := NULL ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bday);
 end;
```

The error is as follows:

Error report -

> ORA-06550: line 5, column 9: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
>   ORA-06550: line 5, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: `'12-oct-09'` is not a `date`, it´s a `varchar`

Answer (score 3):

First let's discuss what is not causing the error, but what is still wrong in your code :)

You are assigning a literal, which is a string, to a variable declared as a date:

```
bday date not null := '13-sep-78';
```

But you are relying on Oracle to do the casting, which is a problem if the string has a different format from your system's default mask. Often Oracle can figure out the date mask and handle the conversion implicitly. Sometimes not, in which case it might hurl `ORA-01843: not a valid month` or similar exception. It is not safe to rely on Oracle implicit casting. Always, always be explicit with data type conversions:

```
bday date not null := to_date('13-sep-1978', 'dd-mon-yyyy');
```

Also, it is bad practice to use two digit years, as Oracle will default it to something you're not expecting, like 0078. Always include the century, it will save you from a world of pain.

**The actual cause of the error**

However, the actual line which is throwing the exception is this one:

```
 bday := NULL ;
```

`ORA-06550` is a compilation error. NULL isn't a string or anything else, so Oracle can't even try to cast it to a date. The code doesn't compile so it doesn't run and there is no way to handle that except by fixing the bug. Once you have done so you'll get the next error. :)

```
SQL> declare
  2    bday date not null := date '2016-09-11';
  3  begin
  4    bday := to_date(null);
  5  end;
  6  /

declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

This one is a runtime error, thrown by assigning NULL to a variable declared as `not null`. To handle the error gracefully you need an exception handler. The most basic for your purpose is ...

```
declare 
   bday date not null := '13-sep-78';
 begin
    bday := '12-oct-09';
    bday := to_date(null);
exception
    when others then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('bday = ['||to_char(bday)||']');
 end;
```

... but you'll want something better In Real Life.

**Note:** Run the above code and see what value the exception handler shows for BDAY. The value is maybe unexpected, which underlines why real code needs better exceptional handling (i.e. more details, more contextual info).

Answer (score 0):

That's a compile-time error and must be fixed before you can actually run the code.

Since your question is on how to display a message instead of the default Oracle error I suspect this is an exercise on exception handling and was done on purpose in order to cause an error to practice catching it in order to display your own message?  If so start here for some basics: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm

If not, let me know in a comment and I'll delete this post.

Answer (score -1):

```
 declare 
   bday varchar2(50) not null := '13-sep-78';
 begin
    bday := '12-oct-09';
    --bday := NULL ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bday);
 end;
```

if you set bday to not null then you cant set it to null value.And bday should be varchar2 or somethingelse due to your value.

Comment: That error occurs because your bday value should be varchar2 for your '13-sep-78' value.And it must be set a value because you state it as "Not null".I commented bday := NULL  line because of this.

Comment: Nope. Oracle can handle some date conversions implicitly. Otherwise we would expect to see `ORA-01843` or similar error message. What causes the particular error message the OP sees is attempting to cast a NULL to a date implicitly. `to_date(null)` throws a different error message. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39368881/146325) to understand more.

Comment: If you run the code on your machine you will see date conversion error message.Yes, it is exactly that oracle can handle some datetime conversions but not this case.Also,priya tried to set a non nullable column with a value if you have noticed?

Comment: Also your answer doesnt meet the correct answer as long as I try to execute your code, it throws ora-06550 exception. which means incorrect type.

Comment: For this case it is appropriate to use varchar2 and convert it whatever date type you want. @priya

Comment: On my machine the implicit date conversions succeed. That's why relying on implicit conversion is bad. You're right that I haven't explained the ORA-06550 exception properly.